# Visual Studio 2010 localization resource files, how to add in strings automatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources

I have a certain project that has a resource directory with a .resx for each language supported in the product.

Right now I am adding these strings by hand using the visual studio 2010 IDE, but because there are a large number of strings, this manual management of these resources can get tricky, and something can easily get omitted in perhaps just 1 .resx file.

Do you get a good resource addon for visual studio 2010, that will allow you to sync and validate a group of resx files? The built in functionality for handling resx seems the same as it was in 2008, and requires a lot of manual effort.

I guess what would be nice would be to have the ability to define all resources in the main language, then have these strings carried across to the remaining languages automatically.

Does such functionality exist? Even a good codeplex project perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those of you guys with the same problem I found this - http://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com/, seems very good.

Comment: Good find. ReSharper 5.0 also has a side-by-side string resource editor, and a refactoring feature that can move a string literal in code to a resource file.

Comment: @Allon, thanks - yet another reason to purchase ReSharper. When I get my next bonus I have to do this.

Comment: Oh god it looks so good,just take a look at this pic on the home page http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/media/images/ZetaResourceEditor-02-01.png

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Localizer](https://visuallocalizer.codeplex.com) is free, supports snychronization of resource files (among other things) and works in Visual Studio 2010 (also in 2008 and 2012).